# Why didn't Anamaria demand a new ship after the Interceptor was destroyed?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean

In Pirates of the Caribbean, the Curse of the Black Pearl, Anamaria's ship was stolen by Jack Sparrow. Eventually, Will Turner and Jack Sparrow offer her the Interceptor as a replacement.

The crew (under Jack), sail to Isla de Meurta and eventually the Interceptor is destroyed by the Black Pearl.

Doesn't that mean that Jack still owes Anamaria a ship? Why doesn't Anamaria make a claim for the Black Pearl or demand that Jack give her another ship?

Comment: I guess and it's evident from the movie that in the end she becomes a part of Black Pearl's crew.